# How can i schedule my Code in Python at every 30 minutes increment after a particular time

Tags: python, datetime, time, scheduled-tasks

I have a time - "09:20:45"
And I want to schedule my code after every 30 minutes of this time - "09:20:45".

I don't know how can I do this?

```
schedule.every(30).minutes.do(output_file_exporting)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

where `output_file_exporting` is my function name.

So I want to run my code after 09:20:45 on the increment of every 30 minutes
like -

```
09:50:45
10:20:45
10:50:45
11:20:45
11:50:45
```

on these time my code should be run.

Comment: Your code already runs every 30 minutes.  So, are you asking how to wait until 09:20:45?

Comment: @TimRoberts let's assume i give a time 09:20 so I want that 09:50 my code will run and then 10:20 my code will run.

Comment: @TimRoberts Not only wait but also if 09:20 already gone but it will know that it has to run 09:20 + 30 minute, so it will run at 09:50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this harder than it needs to be.  You just do it like you describe it.

```
import time
import datetime

while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now.hour >= 9 and now.minute in (20,50):
        break
    time.sleep(60)

output_file_exporting()
schedule.every(30).minutes.do(output_file_exporting)
...
```